# Parsing JSON response in Android

Tags: android, json, foursquare

I am writing a httpget request for android that queries the foursquare api for nearby event. The JSON responce I receive back is

```
{"groups": [
{
  "type": "Nearby",
  "venues": [
    {
      "id": 2587838,
      "name": "Marriott Druids Glen Hotel Newtownmountkennedy",
      "primarycategory": {
        "id": 79281,
        "fullpathname": "Travel:Resort",
        "nodename": "Resort",
        "iconurl": "http://foursquare.com/img/categories/travel/resort.png"
      },
      "address": "Newtownmountkennedy",
      "city": "Newtownmountkennedy",
      "state": "",
      "verified": false,
      "geolat": 53.091717,
      "geolong": -6.079162,
      "stats": {
        "herenow": "0"
      },
      "distance": 5596
    },
```

There can be many of these venues. I can get it to print out the venues information using this code

```
InputStream instream = entity.getContent();
String result= convertStreamToString(instream);
Log.i("Hoosheer0",result);

// A Simple JSONObject Creation
JSONObject json=new JSONObject(result);
JSONArray venues = json.getJSONArray("groups");
//JSONArray docsArray = jObject.getJSONArray("docs");
for (int i = 0; i<venues.length();i++){
    String name = venues.getJSONObject(i).optString("venues");
    //String venueName = name.
    Log.i("This is a name... pleasse", name);
}

instream.close();
```

How can I access the geolat & geolong values?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I believe placing this code inside your for-loop should do the trick:

```
JSONObject venueObject = venues.getJSONObject(i);
double geoLat = venueObject.getDouble("geolat");
double geoLong = venueObject.getDouble("geolong");
```

Comment: this returns a error
"No value for geolat" Is it because it is inside of venue?

Comment: @Christina: umh, yes `"geolat"` *is* inside a venue (according to your example). That's why I in my code first get a single `JSONObject` representing a venue (from the `JSONArray venues`), and then get the latitude and longitude from the `venueObject`. Make sure spelling is correct, and also step through the code in the debugger to examine the values of the `venueObject` in more detail if needed.

Comment: Just noticed that the { around the groups did not copy. I think this is why it won't allow me to access the geolat?? I have now edited the Q. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

You can check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/338586/a-better-java-json-library) and pick a JSON library to use to get at those values.