# How to read JSON values in android

Tags: android, json

Friends I have a json response like this

```
{"status":"1","responseCode":"1000","response":{"actorGuid":"1","daRemarks":"Device is Nonoperational","serialNumber":"1234567"}}
```

I am successfully fetching the status code using

```
String statusStr =  jsonObject.getString("status");
```

but I also need the serialNumber so please tell how do I fetch it. Please help me with the entire code to fetch it.

Regards

Comment: Try this - http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parsing JSON response in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4307380/parsing-json-response-in-android)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try below code

```
String serial= jsonObject.getJSONObject("response").getString("serialNumber");
```

Answer (score 2):

```
String serial = jsonObject.getJSONObject("response").getString("serialNumber");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
JSONObject responseJsonObject =  jsonObject.getJSONObject("response");
 String serialNumberStr =  responseJsonObject.getString("serialNumber");
```