# How to parse JSON array into the android spinner from asp.net webservice which returns string as below

Tags: android, json, spinner, android-spinner, arrays

```
[
{
    "value": "--NA--",
    "id": "251"
},
{
    "value": "Adilabad",
    "id": "1346"
},
{
    "value": "Yavatmal",
    "id": "1478"
}
]
```

How to parse above json into android spinner from json webservice.

I have also gone through many solutions but did not get there.
 I tried this but it was not working for me

```
public class SpinnerDemo extends Activity {

//JSON node names
private static final String TAG_DATA = "data";
private static final String TAG_CREATED_AT = "created_at";
private static final String TAG_ID_DRINK = "id";
private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
private static final String TAG_PRICE = "price";
private static final String TAG_UPDATED_AT = "updated_at";
private static final String MAP_API_URL = "http://domainname.com/webservice/WSHMS.asmx?op=GetCityList";
private BackGroundTask bgt;

Spinner drinkField;

ArrayList<Drink> drinkList = new ArrayList<Drink>();

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.spinner_main);
    buildDrinkDropDown();
}

private void buildDrinkDropDown() {

    List<NameValuePair> apiParams = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
    apiParams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("call", "drinkList"));

    bgt = new BackGroundTask(MAP_API_URL, "GET", apiParams);

    try {
        JSONObject drinkJSON = bgt.execute().get();
        // Getting Array of drinks
        JSONArray drinks = drinkJSON.getJSONArray(TAG_DATA);

        // looping through All drinks
        for (int i = 0; i < drinks.length(); i++) {

            JSONObject d = drinks.getJSONObject(i);

            // Storing each json item in variable

            String id = d.getString(TAG_ID_DRINK);
            String createdAt = d.getString(TAG_CREATED_AT);
            String updatedAt = d.getString(TAG_UPDATED_AT);
            String price = d.getString(TAG_PRICE);
            String name = d.getString(TAG_NAME);



            // add drink
            drinkList.add(new Drink( createdAt ,id, name, price,updatedAt ));
        }
```

I used this code but not getting it...
Please help me on this

Comment: try posting your **gone through many solutions** code.
Then there might be someone to help you. Your question is too vague.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4307380/parsing-json-response-in-android

Comment: can u plz clarify what is the problem ? u cannot parse the json?or there is problem in setting value in spinner? are u getting values in String id = d.getString(TAG_ID_DRINK);... ?

Comment: I used this code by editing this code but I want some sourse code which can help me

Comment: @user2095997 kindly i would suggest change in json from [{"value":"--NA--","id":"251"},{"value":"Adilabad","id":"1346"},{"value":"Yavatmal","id":"1478"}] To {{"value":"--NA--","id":"251"},{"value":"Adilabad","id":"1346"},{"value":"Yavatmal","id":"1478"}} I think this may resolve ur problem

Comment: ok i can help u but plz can u tell me the repsonse u r getting is String??

Comment: what error you are getting? you have no object named 'name' , 'price' and so on. you just have 'id' and 'value' in your json response.

Comment: @Viraj try this `JSONArray drinks = bgt.execute().get()` and in for loop `String id = d.getString("value");`
            `String createdAt = d.getString(T"id");`

Comment: hello everyone I followed just above code but I need some better example which can parse my JSON array. is it possible can anyone provide me the code so that I can better understand the parsing

Comment: what you have posted is a json array without a name. so you can do as above. Also the json has just id and value.

Comment: I need just a value please provide some code if you can

Comment: @Android28 I am not getting any response

Comment: @Viraj  `bgt.execute().get()` is not returning anything i guess. check your asynctask post your asynctask code

Comment: @viraj Alright is it possible for me to view the response weblink ?if not then i need to manipulate in code to fetch the answer from string which is not good idea

Comment: @Viraj this `http://www.domainname.com/webservice/WSHMS.asmx?op=GetCityList1` does not show any json. check your link if it returns a json

Comment: @Android28 sorry but it is confidential.

Comment: @Viraj i was asking for weblink only not the code dear

Comment: @Viraj hey the link u posted is providing error page

Comment: you want the webservice link??

Comment: yup if possible i can provide u the solution if possible mail me

Comment: I dont have your email ID

Comment: plz see my profile u will get there

Comment: I mailed you check it

Comment: @Viraj i havnt received yet kindly check again

Comment: Now check it I send again

Comment: ok got it will post you kindly hold

Comment: ok dear waiting for your response.

Comment: You should learn [**JSON Parsing**](http://www.technotalkative.com/android-json-parsing/) in Android. Once you learn, you can easily prepare ArrayList or Array of data, prepare adapter with it and then set it to Spinner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hi kindly find the sample code attached here for the problem its asmx service and gets json as output from there : here is the code and plz put ur service urls accordingly : https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=8FBD3A73D6D8BFC1!233&authkey=!AKVwa6BLk0nF5sU

Answer (score 3):

You can refer below code
For the json

```
[ 
{
  "name" : "Test",
  "id" : 512
}, {
  "name" : "Test2",
  "id" : 573
}, {
  "name" : "Test3",
  "id" : 585
}
]
```

Parse Like this

```
    ArrayList<String> arrProducts = new ArrayList<String>();

    try {
        JSONArray valarray = new JSONArray(jsonstring);
        for (int i = 0; i < valarray.length(); i++) {

            String str = valarray.getJSONObject(i).getString("name");
            arrProducts.add(str);
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON", "There was an error parsing the JSON", e);
    }
```

And then you can set spinner like this

```
        ArrayAdapter<String> productAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                            MyActivity.this,
                            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, arrProducts);

        productAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        productSpinner.setAdapter(productAdapter);
```